# How to use staticman with React (Gatsby)?

Tags: reactjs, forms, gatsby

As said here https://github.com/eduardoboucas/staticman/issues/243
, `staticman` through their centralized API is not working due to having reached certain quotas

As such, `staticman` is becoming a *github app* to extend these quotas, but there's still no official documentation to get it running.

How is this made?

Comment: The use of public API is now discouraged by the app's maintainer: https://github.com/eduardoboucas/staticman/issues/317#issuecomment-56525006

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/robinmetral/eaudepoisson

1. Create a github repository
2. Install the staticman app in that repository, found here https://github.com/apps/staticman-net
3. Create a configuration file `staticman.yml` in the root of the repository, look at the docs for configuration https://staticman.net/docs/configuration
   and at the repo https://github.com/robinmetral/eaudepoisson

Important, the name of the property of `staticman.yml` is `comments:`, this property is what goes to the direction of your repo. So, if you want to send the comments to `your_repo/markdown/website_comments` then your `path` in `staticman.yml` should be `path: "markdown/website_comments"`), but see below that your url does not refer to the folder structure but to the `staticman.yml` property

4. Create a `/markdown/website_comments` folder in your repo (not really necessary, the folder structure will be created with the first comment)
5. Create a `form`, I've done it with forms provided by `react.semantic-ui.com`

```js
<Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <Form.Input name="name" onChange={changeUserName} placeholder="what" />
    <Form.TextArea name="message" onChange={changeuserMessage} placeholder="what2" />
    <Form.Button>Submit</Form.Button>
</Form>
```

6. Add the logic to send the previous form, where the `form` sends the `data` to `https://dev.staticman.net/v3/entry/github/`**{my github user}**`/`**{my repo}**`/master/comments/` (change the github user and repo name)

```js
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState(() => '')
  const [userMessage, setUserMessage] = useState(() => '')
  const wait = ms => new Promise((r, j) => setTimeout(r, ms))

  let changing = 0 // to create a buffer to avoid changing state always, the browser gets slow otherwise
  const changeUserName = async (e, { value }) => {
    changing++
    let prev_changing = changing
    await wait(100)
    if (prev_changing === changing) setUserName(value)
  }

  const changeuserMessage = async (e, { value }) => {
    changing++
    let prev_changing = changing
    await wait(100)
    if (prev_changing === changing) setUserMessage(value)
  }

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const formdata = new FormData()
    formdata.set('fields[name]', userName)
    formdata.set('fields[message]', userMessage)
    const json = {}
    formdata.forEach((value, prop) => (json[prop] = value))
    const formBody = Object.keys(json)
      .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(json[key]))
      .join('&')

    // in the repo, create a folder named 'comments'
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://dev.staticman.net/v3/entry/github/{my github user}/{my repo}/master/comments/',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: formBody,
      }
    )
    console.log(response)
  }
```

And that's it, or at least it seems to work in my hands

Comment: The app's maintain suggests users to stay away from any public instance and set up his/her own instance in https://github.com/eduardoboucas/staticman/issues/317#issuecomment-56525006.